# How do I reorient images when storing on S3?

Tags: java, image, amazon-s3, playframework-2.0, multipartform-data

I'm storing images on S3 for use in emails. When I view the image in an email, some of the images are rotated. I'm uploading using the AmazonS3Client, and uploading images using MultipartFormData in a Play2 app like this:

```
    Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    String[] pics = new String[]{"picture1", "picture2", "picture3"};
    String[] fileNames = new String[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
        Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart picture = body.getFile(pics[i]);

        if (picture != null) {
            String fileName = picture.getFilename();
            play.Logger.info("fileName: " + fileName);
            File file = picture.getFile();

            String existingBucketName = "yadayadayada";
            String keyName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(existingBucketName, keyName + "-" + fileName, file);
            putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead); // public for all
            s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
            fileNames[i] = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/yadayadayada/" + keyName + "-" + fileName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, all of image processing and what not has to be done at your end. S3 is dumb storage for most parts.

Comment: Ya, what's weird is it's oriented correctly before I upload it. When I open the email with the image link, it's upside down.